# Can we send logs to multiple locations from a single docker logging driver

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose

I want to send logs to multiple locations from a docker logging driver, is it possible with any logging driver?

Comment: Which logging driver?

Comment: with which logging drivers it is possible? is it possible with syslog or gelf?

Answer (score 0):

For php you can use Monolog. 
Find monolog here,
https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog

Monolog is not a driver, its a php package.

It depends on your setup.Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I am using docker, I want application logs sent to multiple locations using a single logging driver. I am using docker CE, so I cannot use multiple logging drivers. Is it possible to write a custom logging driver which does that?